# Haskell quadratic equation root

Tags: haskell

Haskell program which shows the two roots and in the case that the equation has no real roots or has all values as roots should return zero.

```
functionRoot :: Float -> Float -> Float -> (Float,Float)        
functionRoot a b c = if d < 0 then error "0" else (x, y)
                        where x = e + sqrt d / (2 * a)
                        y = e - sqrt d / (2 * a)
                        d = b * b - 4 * a * c
                        e = - b / (2 * a)
```

ERROR: file:.\roots.hs:4 - Syntax error in input (unexpected symbol "y")
any thought?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to indent definitions under `where` further.

```
functionRoot a b c = if d < 0 then error "0" else (x, y)
                        where
                          x = e + sqrt d / (2 * a)
                          y = e - sqrt d / (2 * a)
                          d = b * b - 4 * a * c
                          e = - b / (2 * a)
```

Comment: Those need to be indented even further still. The first non-whitespace token sets the indentation for a block; in this case, that's the `x` in the first binding, so all the remaining bindings must line up with that `x`.